# Bind DataGrid using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datagridview

Is it possible to set the datasource of a datagrid view using ajax?  My objective is to bind a datagrid on clicking a hyperlink(in the same page). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `LinkButton` Instead

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set DataSource here .....
}

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <%--  GridView--%>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```